# Finding the percent of a division fast and mentally

Tags: divisibility, mental-arithmetic

3/8= (0.125*3) = 0.375 = 37.5% is easy to calculate mentally but is there a better way to find the percent of the following divisions fast and mentally?

1. 3.5/8
2. 4.5/7

Comment: Have you tried doing this mentally? Though I see 1 upvote here, this could end up becoming a downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try multiplying the fractions by 2/2 so as to remove the mixing of decimals with fractions. After that, it simply becomes 7/16 which is 7*(1/16), yielding 7*0.0625 or 0.4375 (43.75%). 9/14 is a little trickier to mentally approximate. 100/14 is 7 and 1/7, and 100/7 is 14 with a remainder of 2. Therefore 1/14 is approximately equal to .0714, so 9/14 would yield 0.6426 or 64.46% (in reality it is closer to 64.685%, but the approximation seems reasonable enough). Hope this helps!